# How can I create a 16x9 box with two 16x9 boxes stacked beside it, with captions?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm trying to create the above layout with CSS, but can't quite figure it out. Each 16x9 rectangle is an image. The layout needs to be responsive. Any overflow on the captions will be hidden, so they'll always be 1 line.

https://9elements.com/blog/building-a-combined-css-aspect-ratio-grid/ got me most of the way there, however the addition of the captions seems to screw the math up, and I can't figure out how to adjust for it.

EDIT: The below snippet is what I tried, but obviously it's not correct. Because the column on the right has 2 captions and the left hand box has 1 caption, the aspect ratio of 48/18 is no longer correct. I think if I used a padding hack instead of `aspect-ratio` I could use `calc` to somehow account for the addition of the captions? But I don't understand the math well enough to even know where to begin with that.

```css
.row {
    aspect-ratio: 48/18;
    display: flex;
    max-width: 50rem;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.column {
    aspect-ratio: 16/18;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.item {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.img {
    aspect-ratio: 16/9;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080/eee?text=16:9" class="img" />
    caption goes here
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080/eee?text=16:9" class="img" />
      caption goes here
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080/eee?text=16:9" class="img" />
      caption goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Post the code you've tried!

Comment: I would definitely use a [CSS grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout), rather than the flex approach used in that link.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You're expected to make an attempt and show your code.

Comment: How tall do you want the caption elements to be (e.g. 1.2em….)

Comment: @AHaworth Ideally 1rem text and another 1rem of margin in between the boxes within the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs a little bit of algebra to find the widths of the larger image and the smaller ones.

The calculation depends on knowing 3 things: the overall width you want, this is called --w in the snippet, the height you want the caption spaces to be. This is called --c in the snippet and the gap between grid figures, --g.

Start by noticing the obvious:
w = w1 + w2 where w1, w2 are the widths of the bigger and smaller images respectively. [You can adjust further for border widths and/or gaps if you want]

And then noticing that the height of the bigger image is 2*height of a smaller image + caption height:

w1x9/16 = (2x(w2x9/16)) + c

So we've got two simultaneous equations from which we can work out that:

w1 = (w + (c x 8 / 9)) x 2 /3

w2 = (w / 3) - (c x 16 / 27)

From these we can set up a CSS grid as in this snippet:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  --w: min(50rem, 100vw);
  /* the width of the two columns */
  --c: 1.2em;
  /* the height of a caption element */
  --g: 1rem;
  /* the gap */
  width: calc(var(--w) + var(--g));
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: var(--g);
  grid-template-columns: calc((var(--w) + (var(--c) * 8 / 9)) * 2 / 3) calc((var(--w) / 3) - (var(--c) * 16 / 27));
  grid-template-rows: calc(((var(--w) / 3) - (var(--c) * 16 / 27)) * 9 /16) var(--c) calc(((var(--w) / 3) - (var(--c) * 16 / 27)) * 9 /16) var(--c);
}

.row>figure {
  display: contents;
}

.row> :nth-child(1) img {
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 3;
}

.row> :nth-child(1) figcaption {
  grid-column: 1 / span 1;
  grid-row: 4 / span 1;
}

.row>nth-child(2) img {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 1;
}

.row>nth-child(2) figcaption {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 2 / span 1;
}

.row> :nth-child(3) img {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 3 / span 1;
}

.row> :nth-child(3) figcaption {
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;
  grid-row: 4 / span 1;
}

.img {
  aspect-ratio: 16/9;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <figure class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080/eee?text=16:9" class="img" />
      <figcaption>caption goes here</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080/eee?text=16:9" class="img" />
      <figcaption>caption goes here</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080/eee?text=16:9" class="img" />
      <figcaption>caption goes here</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
</body>
```

Note: I changed the HTML to replace the item divs with a figure element containing an img and a figcaption as that seemed more logical.

Comment: Definitely would not have figured that out on my own, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using CSS Grid as below

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.left-box {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left-box img {
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.left-box .caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.right-box {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.right-box-item {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.right-box-item:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 56.25%
}

.right-box-item img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="left-box">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080/eee?text=16:9" alt="Left Image">
      <div class="caption">Caption for the left image</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-box">
      <div class="right-box-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080/eee?text=16:9" alt="Top Image">
        <div class="caption">Caption for the top image</div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-box-item">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080/eee?text=16:9" alt="Bottom Image">
        <div class="caption">Caption for the bottom image</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but the left image is not 16x9 when I run the snippet ?

Comment: @Stu edited the snippet. Please have a look

Comment: The two boxes in the column are now not 16:9

Comment: @Stu I have made the changes. Now everything is 16:9 as per your requirement

Comment: It looks like you've just got the captions absolute positioned on top of the images, which might be a good alternative approach (the caption element could have an opacity to make the text readable, while still being able to see the image below) if nothing else works but isn't what I'm trying to achieve. Ideally the captions would sit below the image, and the full image would be visible.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with 'table' element if you can use. It may help much, I guess.
The code would be like below;

```
<table>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <img src='img1'/>
      <p>caption 1</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src='img2'/>
      <p>caption 2</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <img src='img3'/>
      <p>caption 3</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```